# Unity 2D Auto Scrolling Shooter

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm making a 2D shooter with a five layer, auto scrolling background and am having trouble keeping the player object on screen and the ability to control it at the same time after I hit "play" in the editor.

A little information up front, in the Hierarchy, I have it set up so that the camera parents the background. If I separate the background from the camera, the scene and game view goes blank. If I make the background the parent, the game view goes blank, so I keep the camera parented to the background.

The problem is the player object can't be controlled or seen in scene view if parented by the camera or background but is visible in the game view. The player object goes away from game view, if separate from either one but sticks around and can be controlled in scene view. So I can either see the player object in game view and not control it, or control it in scene view and not see it in game view. (hope that makes sense)

Hitting "play" in all scenarios causes the entire background zip off really fast to the left in scene view. Having the player object separate from camera and background makes it stay in scene view. Having the player object child the camera or background makes them snatch it from scene view with them. As long as the camera parents the background, the background is always visible and running/scrolling correctly in game view.

I've messed around with sorting layers and that seems to have no effect on the order the layers show up in. I made a sorting layer for "background", "player" and "camera" and set the orders in many different ways but nothing happens. Manipulating each object in the Hierarchy is the only thing that seems to have some kind of effect.

```
using System.Collections;
```

using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
public float playerSpeed;

```
private Rigidbody2D rb;
private Vector2 leftStickInput;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    GetPlayerInput();
}

private void GetPlayerInput()
{

    leftStickInput = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    Vector2 curMovement = leftStickInput * playerSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

    rb.MovePosition(rb.position + curMovement);
}
```

}

```
    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AutoScroll : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float bGSpeed = -2f;
    Vector2 startpos;
    
    void Start()
    {
        startpos = transform.position;
    }

   
    void Update()
    {
        float newpos = Mathf.Repeat (Time.time * bGSpeed, 5000);
        transform.position = startpos + Vector2.left * newpos;
    }
}


    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Parallax : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float length, startpos;
    public GameObject cam;
    public float parallaxEffect;
    
    void Start()
    {
        startpos = transform.position.x;
        length = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().bounds.size.x;
    }

    
    void Update()
    {
        float temp = (cam.transform.position.x * (1 - parallaxEffect));
        float dist = (cam.transform.position.x * parallaxEffect);

        transform.position = new Vector3(startpos + dist, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);

        if (temp > startpos + length) startpos += length;
        else if (temp < startpos - length) startpos -= length;
    }
}

[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0LhS.png
```

Comment: Could you please add some code to your question? Also a picture would be nice :)

Comment: GHESTAS, I just updated with code and a link to an image. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: I'm on to something. I disabled my auto scroll code and the problem is resolved. The character is both visible and playable on the Scene and Game view. Only problem is this would be great if all I wanted was a static background. I need the background to move, so now I have to figure that out.